# Accessing each CalendarDay in Calendar Control without using the DayRender Event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to manipulate the appearance of the an ASP.NET calendar control.  I have data that I need to display on the calendar control but I don't want to access the data from within the DayRender event.  How do I access the CalendarDay object that represents each day in the calendar without being within the DayRender event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reflector, it appears that OnDayRender is the only place the CalendarDay class is exposed, so there isn't any other option without developing a custom solution.  Even with a custom calendar control, you could only collect the CalendarDay objects within RenderDays/OnDayRender.  That is the method they are explicitly created, unfortunately.

Comment: Seems you are correct.  The problem is I have to write a lot of clunky code to cache the data from the original request that I need to manipulate the calendar.  Really don't like that calendar control...thanks for your help!